# Can't access my administration panel

Tags: users

I was playing around with my website, which was built by a developer long time ago, and I remove the permission for the "administrator" role, and now as a "superadmin" I can't access the Drupal panel of my own site.

Can someone help me figure out how can I access the control panel?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Drush commands instead like

[Drush urol command](https://drushcommands.com/drush-8x/user/user-add-role/)

Or update existing role with the proper permission to access your backend admin

[Drush add permistion command](https://drushcommands.com/drush-8x/role/role-add-perm/)

Comment: Ahmad thank you for the answer. Although, I am not a developer and I don't understand how to use Drush. I was able to access the super admin by going into www.mydomain.com/user/login, but then I don't see the menu bar or dashboard where I can add the login block and permissions again. What do I do?